# OSのイメージファイルの作成方法が分からない

Tags: linux, c, unix, kernel, assembly

現在、Linux上でOS開発をしようと考えています。

http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev11.html

上記のサイトの下にある**DOWNLOAD DEMO HERE**でソースコードをダウンロードし、コンパイルすることはできますがバイナリファイルを連結してQEMUで起動することができません。
QEMUで起動可能なイメージファイルをLinuxで作成するにはどうすればいいですか？

自分なりに試したOSの連結方法を下記に示します。(失敗した方法です)

```
cat KRNLDR.SYS KRNL.SYS > KERNEL

dd if=/dev/zero of=os.img bs=512 count=10000
dd if=Boot1.bin of=os.img bs=512 conv=notrunc
dd if=KERNEL of=os.img bs=512 seek=1 conv=notrunc
```

この方法ではダメでした。
どうすればうまく起動できるでしょうか？知識のある方よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux上でのフロッピーディスクイメージ作成に成功しました。
以下は自分が書いたMakefileです。

```
boot1.bin: Boot1.asm
    nasm -f bin $^ -o $@
KRNLDR.SYS: Stage2.asm
    nasm -f bin $^ -o $@
KRNL.SYS: Stage3.asm
    nasm -f bin $^ -o $@

k.img: boot1.bin KRNL.SYS KRNLDR.SYS
    mformat -f 1440 -C -B boot1.bin -i $@ ::
    mcopy KRNLDR.SYS -i $@ ::
    mcopy KRNL.SYS -i $@ ::

run: k.img
    qemu-system-i386 -drive file=k.img,format=raw,if=floppy -boot a
```

Answer (score 0):

"DOWNLOAD DEMO HERE"をクリックしてダウンロードした"Demo4.zip"というファイルを展開すると、３つのディレクトリ、Stage1、Stage2、Kernel、に展開されました。

各ディレクトリには、アセンブラ(ASM)で書かれたソースプログラムと、"BUILE.bat"というファイルが入っています。
"Kernel/BUILE.bat"の内容は次のようになっています。

```
nasm -f bin Stage3.asm -o KRNL.SYS
copy KRNL.SYS  A:\KRNL.SYS

pause
```

同様に、Stage1とStage2の下のBUILD.batは、

```
nasm -f bin Boot1.asm -o Boot1.bin

PARTCOPY Boot1.bin 0 3 -f0 0 
PARTCOPY Boot1.bin 3E 1C2 -f0 3E 

pause
```

と

```
nasm -f bin Stage2.asm -o KRNLDR.SYS

copy KRNLDR.SYS  A:\KRNLDR.SYS

pause
```

それぞれのバッチ(bat)ファイルは、ブートドライブ(Aドライブに挿入されたフロッピーディスク）を起動ディスクにする操作の一部を行っているのではないかと思われます。(どのバッチファイルも、アセンブラのソースプログラムをアッセンブルして、出来上がったファイルをAドライブに書き込んでいますので）

"Stage1/BUILE.bat"、"Stage2/BUILE.bat"、"Kernel/BUILE.bat"を順に実行し、そのままマシンを再起動（そうすれば、Aドライブのフロッピーを使って起動されるはず）してみてはいかがでしょうか。